# Absolute link to another workbook on the network

Tags: hyperlink, absolute-path, excel

I currently have a excel workbook that has values being pulled from other workbooks in the same folder on the network.

Wherever this workbook is opened, the link to the workbook changes, and no longer works, as it stays relative to where you are opening it from. I need the path to point to the same place every time.

Example for where it should be pointing.

```
='\\1.1.1.1\intranet\lp\files\test\[metricsheet.xlsm]information'!$B$13
```

Is there a way to keep this path (absolute) without VBA?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the current formula/reference?

Comment: That is the current, since it's stored in the directory it should be pointing to. But when it's moved (for example to my desktop) the patch changes to point to my desktop. This doesn't work because there's no file for it to reference in that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
='\\1.1.1.1\intranet\lp\files\test[metricsheet.xlsm]information'!$B$13
```

If the first part (1.1.1.1) is an ip address, you need two slashes. A single slash just refers to a directory, not a server.

Comment: that's my example I posted, which doesn't work. It changes if you move the file. I'm looking for an absolute reference. The first dash is in my post, but SO was hiding it.

Comment: Found out the issue. This path format does work.. however the relative path was matching the absolute path I wanted, as it was stored in the same folder. Moving it out and then copy/pasting the same path back in, caused it to stay.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue. This path format does work.. however the relative path was matching the absolute path I wanted, as it was stored in the same folder. Moving it out and then copy/pasting the same path back in, caused it to stay.